# Is there an archive of older rules or rules that changed in the platform?

Tags: discussion, rules, stack-overflow-history

I am doing some research on the Stack Overflow platform and I would like to learn if anyone keeps track of changes on the rules since the creation of the web site. For example questions were getting 5 points per up-vote but that has been changed to 10 now.

Comment: Most of them were brought along with [tag:featured] announcements, either here or at [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions). So you might look these up, at least for major changes.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445)*

Comment: Note: It's going to be a pain in whatever you've got for a back end to even find some rules. Site practically runs off oral tradition .

Comment: Not *quite* oral, @user4581301: oral via Meta sites. So there *is* actually an archive. That brings us into the realm of possibility at least, although there will still be pain aplenty in *finding* it.

Comment: I'm a big fan of simple rule sets. In my perfect world, there's one rule: Don't be a dick. Thing is no one agrees on what it means to be a dick. And there are people who don't grasp that repeatedly being just slightly less then a dick sums up to being a dick. So we need rules.

Comment: I agree that would be mostly sufficient for a Code of Conduct, @user4581301 (in fact, it's essentially what we had and used as a CoC for many years, but spelled a bit differently: "be nice"). However, it doesn't approach an explanation of what is on-topic or other procedural issues, so I think it is on-face insufficient.

Comment: @user4581301 there's also lots of rules about what is a good and on-topic post or not, none of which have to do with dick-ness.

Comment: @user4581301 There are also rules on the sort of language you can use in comments; using bad language once is one thing, but if you do it repeatedly then, well, it sums up...

Comment: Pretty <expletive deleted>ing familiar with language violations. Not here, mind you.

Comment: Kind of corollary: nobody knows completely what the current rules/features are.

Comment: Note that (AFAICR) questions were initially granted 10 points for an up-vote, then it was reduced to 5 points, and then it was changed back to 10 points.  I believe there were global rep recalculations for both changes.  There was also a fair amount of gnashing of teeth and wailing when the amount was reduced.

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is to only be strict on questions and answers that are from 2012 and beyond, anything before that I consider the "SO wild west" and don't close vote or flag unless I find something that gives a strong urge to nuke from orbit. If you follow that rule of thumb, maybe you'd also not want to go back further in time with examining rule changes.

Comment: You can't have clearly defined rules! How can you punish people for thinking the wrong way if they can point to the rules to defend themselves? Don't you know fear of the unknown is a much more effective way to manipulate? If you clearly define rules, people could argue to have them changed! Don't be ridiculous, get with the program. Do you want to subvert this platform millions of people rely on or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a community-maintained list of [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) over on the global Meta. All of the usual caveats apply, namely that it is community-maintained and thus not guaranteed to be comprehensive.

Another option is, as πάντα ῥεῖ suggested, looking through the questions here and on the global Meta, which will contain an announcement of any major rules change. (Some of the feature/design changes aren't documented or even announced on Meta, but virtually any *rules* change would be.) Still, this is a pretty herculean task, especially if you don't know what we would have called the original rule and therefore can't intuit the correct search terms to use.

If worst comes to worst, and you want to know the details of a specific rule, then you could ask a new question about it here on Meta (or [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com) on Meta). At least one of us is old enough to remember, and can probably point you to the relevant prior Meta discussions surrounding it. But do try to do this sparingly. Stack Exchange archaeology can be interesting, but only in relatively small doses.